# from firestore map to StreamBuilder => ListView.Builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to show the songs list inside a specific document and only the KEY(name) not the value. Every song should load in list but all of them load in one widget.
and it loads the 'songs list' from every document(singer) inside firestore and show both KEY and Value.

[image: DB]
[image: APP]

```
class SongsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SongsListState createState() => _SongsListState();
}

class _SongsListState extends State<SongsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('singers').snapshots(),
        builder: (
          context,
          snapshot,
        ) {
          //**if statement**
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/back.png'), fit: BoxFit.contain)),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 300,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                                  spreadRadius: 1.5,
                                  blurRadius: 1.5,
                                  //offset: Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.red[200],
                                  width: 0.5,
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]['songs list']
                                      .toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10, color: Colors.red[500]),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
snapshot.data.documents[index]['songs list']
```

this should return a `map`, therefore assign it to a variable:

```
var result = snapshot.data.documents[index]['songs list'];
```

Then iterate and assign the `key` to the `Text` widget:

```
children: <Widget>[
        for(var res in result.entries) 
          Text(
            res.key,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10, color: Colors.red[500]),
             ),
         ]
```

---

Full code:

```
class SongsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SongsListState createState() => _SongsListState();
}

class _SongsListState extends State<SongsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('singers').snapshots(),
        builder: (
          context,
          snapshot,
        ) {
          //**if statement**
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/back.png'), fit: BoxFit.contain)),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var result = snapshot.data.documents[index]['songs list'];
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 300,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 1.5,
                                blurRadius: 1.5,
                                //offset: Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
                              ),
                            ],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.red[200],
                                width: 0.5,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                        child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              for (var res in result.entries)
                                Text(
                                  res.key,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10, color: Colors.red[500]),
                                ),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also make sure to change the dart version in your `pubspec.yaml` file to the following:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

then execute:

```
 flutter pub get
 flutter clean
```

and restart vscode or android studio.

Comment: thanks @peter. hey peter i am new to flutter. can you correct that in my code from the Question above cuz i tried multiple times and didnt vet it right. thanks in advance

Comment: thanks @peter. its just like what it was. its showing the "songs list" from all the documents (singers), and it shows each list in a single text widget (not a list)