# fetching a specific document from a subcollection in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am creating a password manager app using flutter and data and firebase as a backend service. After a user has logged in, that user access a list of password account he creates in the app. I'm having difficulties to implement a code when a user taps a list from the listtile, I want to fetch a specific data according to the tapped list. Below is the code of my homescreen where saved passwords are printed.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("users")
                .doc(firebaseuser?.uid)
                .collection("passwordProfile")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Loading'),
                );
              }
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((passw) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(passw['appname'])),
                      title: Text(passw['appname']),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Profile()));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            })
```

The above code fetches data from firestore from a subcollection named passwordProfiles and prints on the homescreen. Now what should I do to fetch a specific data when a certain list is clicked from the list tile??

Answer (score 0):

user ListView.builder instead of Listview
It will automatically handle all items in itemBuilder

Comment: can you please elaborate more on that if possible provide a sample code

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315330/from-firestore-map-to-streambuilder-listview-builder